# Flex 4 States -- "correct" syntax

Tags: apache-flex, syntax, adobe, states

OK, can someone please tell me the **REAL** syntax for doing states in mxml in Flex 4???

I've seen both of the following (and implemented both) and don't know which way is "right" or preferred.

#### In the `<fx:Declarations>`

```
<fx:Declarations>
  ...
  <s:State name="state1" />
  <s:State name="state2" />
  <s:State name="state3" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button id="button1" ... />
...
<more components>
```

OR

#### "Top-most" level in a component

```
<s:states>
  <s:State name="state1" />
  <s:State name="state2" />
  <s:State name="state3" />
</s:states>

<s:Button id="button1" ... />
...
<more components>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the second one; but It depends what you're trying to do.

This Syntax:

```
<fx:Declarations>
  ...
  <s:State name="state1" />
  <s:State name="state2" />
  <s:State name="state3" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

Creates three variables inside the component of the class State.  It would be the same as doing something like this in ActionScript:

```
var myState1 : State = new State();
var myState1 : State = new State();
var myState1 : State = new State();
```

When creating states on a component, you probably want to do more than just create a state.  You want to assign the state as a state of the current component.

That is what your second syntax actually does:

```
<s:states>
  <s:State name="state1" />
  <s:State name="state2" />
  <s:State name="state3" />
</s:states>
```

This creates three state variables as an array, and assigns them to the state property of the top level component.  Conceptually like this in ActionScript:

```
var myState1 : State = new State();
var myState1 : State = new State();
var myState1 : State = new State();
this.states = new Array();
this.states.push(myState1);
this.states.push(myState2);
this.states.push(myState3);
```

It is entirely possible that the compiler does some magic on the first syntax to create those state instance and assign them to the states array, but I'm not sure.  I've never seen anyone use that syntax before.  I would expect both approach to compile.  I would only expect the second approach to actually create states on a component that you can switch between.

Comment: No, the first way works just fine.  In fact, that was my syntax when I wrote the question.  At any point in my component code, I can still do `currentState = state1` (or any of the others) using the first way, to correctly change states.  That's why I'm so confused about the difference.

Comment: @istrasci Then the Flex Compiler must be doing some magic under the scenes based on the 'type' of class in the declaration tag.

Comment: I'd advise you to use the second one even if the first one works

Comment: @exort While I don't disagree; what is your reasoning?

Comment: Oh simply because we know exactly what's done, i.e. we create an array of state objects and set it to the States property of the component. We don't have to assume the compiler will do it under the hood. I agree however that the end result would be exactly the same.